# How to store complex numbers in OpenCV matrix?

Tags: opencv, matrix, complex-numbers

I have two matrices A and B, where A & B contains some real numbers. Now I want a complex numbered matrix C, such that: C[0] = A[0] + i B[0].

My question is how create such complex matrix C, and how to pass A, B matrices values into matrix C.

I came to know that, I can create matrix C as follows:

CvMat* C_Matrix = cvCreateMat(5, 5, CV_64FC2);

But now how to pass values of A & B to matrix C_Matrix?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `merge()` function here, See the **[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#merge)**

It says : `Composes a multi-channel array from several single-channel arrays.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is like simply merging two images. But that is not I want. I want to give a complex number as input to a matrix. If u know, please help me.....

Comment: Check this official tutorial on dft : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html