# How can I store complex numbers

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

the problem is to fourie transform ( cv::dft ) a signal with fourie descriptors. So the mat should be complex numbers :(

But my problem is how can make a mat with complex numbers ? 
Please help me to find an example or any other that show me how to store a complex number(RE + IM) to a mat ?

Is there a way to use merge ?

> `merge()`

Comment: yes, that would be a way. please show, what you've got already.

Comment: [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, no, not in this case. opencv would want it in 2 seperate channels (wrong memory alignment)

Comment: @Alf85: Do not add secondary questions as answers. Add them as comments instead. For new questions start separate threads.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer saying:

I think you can use `merge()` function here, See the **[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#merge)**

It says : `Composes a multi-channel array from several single-channel arrays.`
Reference: [How to store complex numbers in OpenCV matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495316/how-to-store-complex-numbers-in-opencv-matrix)

Answer (score 2):

look at the nice [dft sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/cpp/dft.cpp) in the opencv repo, also at the [dft tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html#discretfouriertransform)

so, if you have a Mat real, and a Mat imag (both of type CV_32FC1):

```
Mat planes[] = {real,imag};
Mat complexImg;
merge(planes, 2, complexImg); // complexImg is of type CV_32FC2 now

dft(complexImg, complexImg);

split(complexImg, planes);
// real=planes[0], imag=planes[1];
```